# Future value function in iPhone SDK

Tags: objective-c

I wanted a function which accepts present value, number of years and compound interest rate. It should return me the Future value based on these parameters.

You can see the exact thing that I am looking for at
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_value
(under To determine future value using compound interest)

Does Objective-C has any inbuilt function to do that. If no, could you please provide me any references to write that function.

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, neither Objective-C nor Apple's frameworks include specific financial functions.

It's trivial to implement. The Wikipedia article you link to includes the formula. You might also want to consider something like [QuantLib](http://quantlib.org/index.shtml) if you ever get onto more sophisticated calculations.

The formula -- copied from the Wikipedia article you linked to -- is:

```
FV = PV . (1 + i) ^ t
```

This can be converted into Objective-C mainly by typing:

```
  float fv, pv, i, t;

  pv = 200000.0; // present value
  i  = 0.012;    // interest rate (1.2%)
  t  = 5.0;      // time period

  fv = pv * pow (1.0 + i, t);
```

Comment: What exactly is QuantLib ? How will it help me in finding FV code?

Comment: QuantLib is a library of financial calculations. Did you follow the link?

Comment: I think you've been WAY too generous with your answer here :) btw, I need to sum a list of numbers... is there a call for that?

Comment: Actually, it was Stephen who answered you, I just made a small edit. (Sorry Stephen!)

Answer (score 1):

There would not be anything like this in Objective-C as Objective-C is a language, not a framework.

There's also nothing like this in Cocoa or Cocoa Touch, as they don't typically contain financial functions.