# calculate Future value in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Will the following function for calculating Future value based on present value, interest rate and time period work in iphone?

```
-(float) calcFV: float pv: float interest_rate: float time
{
   float fv, pv, interest_rate, t;

   //pv = 200000.0; // present value
   //i  = 0.012;    // interest rate (1.2%)
   //t  = 5.0;      // time period

   fv = pv * pow (1.0 + interest_rate, time);
   return fv;

}
```

Comment: are you actually having a problem with this code or are you asking if the way your calculating this is correct ?

Comment: actually i wanted to ask both; syntax as well as whether formula is actually correct?

Comment: This is just the accepted answer from your previous question: [Future value function in iPhone SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364688/future-value-function-in-iphone-sdk) Shouldn't you have raised it there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and no!

Despite the fact that your formula is correct, you are declaring pv and interest_rate, as well as passing them in as parameters.

Remove the declarations:

```
-(float) calcFVFromPresentValue: (float) pv interest_rate: (float) interest_rate time: (float) time
{
    float fv;

    //pv = 200000.0; // present value
    //i  = 0.012;    // interest rate (1.2%)
    //t  = 5.0;      // time period

    fv = pv * pow (1.0 + interest_rate, time);
    return fv;

}
```

Incidentally, your .h file should now have this:

```
-(float) calcFVFromPresentValue: (float) pv interest_rate: (float) interest_rate time: (float) time;
```

Comment: For the line -(float) calcFV: float pv: float interest_rate: float time 
I get Expected identifier before float

Comment: Also you can remove fv and return directly the formula, also it kind of feels right to make this an inline function if its going to be called frequently

Comment: Hey Dave..you're now Bang ON target !!

Answer (score 0):

Considering the equation is `current * (1.0+interest)^time`, yes it will.

Comment: Actually I am getting an erron ; Expected identifier before float

Comment: I can't comment on the syntax and semantic as I don't know objective-c. The equation is correct though, as far I as can see.