# Calculate growth rate in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Ref URL; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_value

Earlier similar question; [calculate Future value in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913502/calculate-future-value-in-iphone)

Like we hvae PV (Present value0, FV (Future value), No. of years (N) and growth rate (%)

How can we calculate growth rate (or interest rate) using the other 3 variables in iPhone?

Code for FV below;

```
-(float) calcFVFromPresentValue: (float) pv interest_rate: (float) interest_rate time: (float) time
{
    float fv;

    //pv = 200000.0; // present value
    //i  = 0.012;    // interest rate (1.2%)
    //t  = 5.0;      // time period

    fv = pv * pow (1.0 + interest_rate, time);
    return fv;

}
```

Comment: if you're doing this kind of stuff, definitely read and understand http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-01-04-practical-floating-point.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since r = (FV/PV)^(1/t) - 1, in Objective-C and your variables:

```
-(float) calcRateFromPresentValue:(float)pv futureValue:(float)fv time:(float)time
{
float rate = 0.0;

rate = pow( (fv/pv), (1/time) ) - 1;
return rate;
}
```

note: in the future, try doing it on your own first, we're not code monkeys (i add this edit after i monkey your code of course :p)

edit2: left off the minus 1 in the formula.

Comment: You're BANG ON TARGET with what i want...A 7 ******* to you !!

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for just the equation?  Break it down using algebra.

```
fv = pv * pow (1.0 + interest_rate, time);
fv / pv = pow (1.0 + interest_rate, time); // divide by pv
pow ( fv / pv, 1.0 / time ) = 1.0 + interest_rate; // raise each side by 1/time

// then subtract 1 from each side:
interest_rate = pow ( fv / pv, 1.0 / time ) - 1.0;
```